# Как написать SQL запрос что-бы в таблице отобразить по вторичному ключу 2 колонки из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица в MS SQL SERVER 2008

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [NumberOfFlight]
      ,[AviacompanyID]
      ,[PlaneID]
      ,[toID]
      ,[fromID]
      ,[GoDateTime]
      ,[ArriveDateTime]
      ,[CostOfEcoClass]
      ,[CostOfBusinessClass]
      ,[EcoSold]
      ,[BusSold]
      ,[AllSold]
      ,[Money]
  FROM [airport].[dbo].[FlightsCurrentSet]
```

Столбцы `toID` и `fromID` берут значения из одной таблицы.
Я писал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT AviacompaniesSet.Name AS Авиакомпания, PlanesSet.Model AS Самолёт, CitiesSet.Name AS Откуда, CitiesSet.Name AS Куда, GoDateTime AS [Дата и время отправления], ArriveDateTime AS [Дата и время прибытия], CostOfEcoClass AS [Стоимость эконом класса], CostOfBusinessClass AS [Стоимость бизнес класса], EcoSold AS [Продано билетов эконом класса], BusSold AS [Продано билетов бизнес класса], AllSold AS [Продано всего], [Money] AS [Прибыль]
FROM ([airport].[dbo].FlightsCurrentSet
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].AviacompaniesSet ON AviacompaniesSet.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.AviacompanyID)
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].PlanesSet ON PlanesSet.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.PlaneID
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].CitiesSet ON CitiesSet.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.toID AND CitiesSet.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.fromID
```

Но ничего не выходит у меня. Он мне выводит один и тот же город. Мало того, он не выводит все строки содержащиеся в данной таблице.

Comment: Приведите пример ваших результатов и пример ожидаемых результатов.

Comment: Цепляйте таблицы в запрос по одной и смотрите получающиеся данные что бы понять на каком этапе что то идет не так

Comment: Товарищ @i-one ответил на мой вопрос. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Просто читайте, и таких вопросов не будет. Это же азы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы видимо хотите присоединить одну и ту же таблицы дважды. Для этого им нужно дать разный alias. Вообще, на мой взгляд, с alias-ами код компактнее и читабельнее.

Как-то так:

```
SELECT
    avc.Name AS Авиакомпания,
    ps.Model AS Самолёт,
    ctyFrom.Name AS Откуда,
    ctyTo.Name AS Куда,
    ...
FROM
    [airport].[dbo].FlightsCurrentSet fc
    INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].AviacompaniesSet avc ON avc.Id = fc.AviacompanyID
    INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].PlanesSet ps ON ps.Id = fc.PlaneID
    INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].CitiesSet ctyFrom ON ctyFrom.Id = fc.fromID
    INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].CitiesSet ctyTo ON ctyTo.Id = fc.toID
```

Comment: Да! Это именно то что мне нужно. Работает точь в точь как я хотел. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте два INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT AviacompaniesSet.Name AS [Авиакомпания], PlanesSet.Model AS [Самолёт],
CSFrom.Name AS [Откуда], CSFrom.Name AS [Куда],
GoDateTime AS [Дата и время отправления], ArriveDateTime AS [Дата и время прибытия], CostOfEcoClass AS [Стоимость эконом класса], CostOfBusinessClass AS [Стоимость бизнес класса], EcoSold AS [Продано билетов эконом класса], BusSold AS [Продано билетов бизнес класса], AllSold AS [Продано всего], [Money] AS [Прибыль]
FROM ([airport].[dbo].FlightsCurrentSet
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].AviacompaniesSet ON AviacompaniesSet.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.AviacompanyID)
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].PlanesSet ON PlanesSet.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.PlaneID
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].CitiesSet CSFrom ON CSFrom.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.fromID
INNER JOIN [airport].[dbo].CitiesSet CSTo ON CSTo.Id = FlightsCurrentSet.toID
```

Замечу ещё, что самолёты летают не между городами, а между аэропортами.
И кроме того, речь по идее должна быть про рейсы, а уже на рейсы назначается конкретный самолёт.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку. Учту.